# Batch Script to move and rename if existing

Tags: pdf, batch, script, batch-file

I have a folder that contains thousands of .pdfs  each file named by a 5 or 6 digit account number.  I have a script that will create a folder of the same account number and move the file into it.

```
echo ON
Title  Move files Routine

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    pushd D:\test1\source\

    for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b D:\test1\source\*.pdf') do (
    set filename=%%1&set dirname=!filename:~0,6!

    if not exist D:\test1\source\!dirname! (md D:\test1\source\!dirname!)
    move %%1 D:\test1\source\!dirname!\
    )

PAUSE
```

However, I need to run this script daily as new filed are added to the source directory and if the script moves a file to a directory that already has a file of the same name, it will overwrite it instead of renaming it.  How can I tweak my script to address this problem.  My options appear to be

1. append to existing file (this seems to require additional software)
2. Rename (e.g. 123456.pdf to 123456_001.pdf)
3. Add date to filename (e.g. 123456.pdf to 123456_MMMMddyyyy.pdf)

I am fine with any of these options, I just don't know how to put that in the script.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3), but I suggest you add the current time as well:

```
echo Timestamp = %date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
```

This will output, for instance,

> Timestamp = 2018-03-13-17-18-38

So your batch file would look like this:

```
echo ON
Title  Move files Routine

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    pushd D:\test1\source\

    for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b D:\test1\source\*.pdf') do (
    set filename=%%1&set dirname=!filename:~0,6!

    if not exist D:\test1\source\!dirname! (md D:\test1\source\!dirname!)
    move %%1 D:\test1\source\!dirname!\%%1--%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.pdf
    )

PAUSE
```

Comment: What if two files get moved in the same second? Also, I think you want to use delayed expansion for the variables that pick substrings from the Date and Time variables.

Comment: Thanks glfabro When I run the script with your additions I get this response
D:\test1\source>(set filename=10002.pdf  & set dirname=!filename:~0,6!
 if not exist D:\test1\source\!dirname! (md D:\test1\source\!dirname! )
 move 10002.pdf D:\test1\source\!dirname!\10002.pdf--/15/- 0-Th- 9-45-57.pdf )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
My guess as to the syntax error is how it is formating the date, specifically "/15/"  I have been playing with changing the date format, but unsuccessfully.  It may be based on a locale setting?

Comment: Hmmm that's indeed locale dependent. Type in the command prompt 'echo %date%' and 'echo %time%' and tell me the result

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica A quick and dirty hack would be to add a `timeout 1 >nul` after the `move` command, thereby guaranteeing that there will never be two files moved in the same second - albeit at a cost of slowing down the time the script takes to run